# GETDATE() Msg 241 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server

This SQL statement throws an conversion error on one of my servers:

```
DECLARE @TimeStamp datetime;
SET @TimeStamp = GETDATE();

INSERT INTO Lookups 
    SELECT 
        newid() AS Id, 
        'Type' AS Type, Name, 
        'A.Miller' AS CreatedName, 
        'A.Miller' AS ChangedName,
        @TimeStamp AS CreatedDate, 
        @TimeStamp AS ChangedDate 
    FROM 
        [DBServer].[Database].[dbo].[LkValues] 
    WHERE 
        NOT Name IS NULL OR Name = ''
```

Error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, Status 1, Row 5
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I tried it with several variants as well wihout a variable to convert is us format and without converting, without success:

```
CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 110) AS CreatedDate, 
CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 110) AS ChangedDate
```

A `SELECT` statement without `INSERT` results in values which looks all pretty well.

I am running it on a SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50.2550.0).

On another server the command runs without any problem, why?

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Lookups] 
(
     [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
     [Typ] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
     [Name] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
     [ChangedDate] [datetime] NULL,
     [ChangedName] [varchar](32) NULL,
     [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
     [CreatedName] [varchar](32) NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Lookups]
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` for `Lookups`?

Comment: Can you post the DDL of your table `[DBServer].[Database].[dbo].[LkValues]` please? Inserting the value of `GETDATE()` into a `datetime`won't create the error.

Comment: See Larnu's answer below - if you don'r specify the columns to insert into, the select MUST be in the same order as the columns in the table. In this case, you're trying to put "A.Miller" into changed date. The names of the column in the select don't mean anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very much a guess at this time, however, I would *guess* that the order of the columns is not the same as that in the `SELECT` statement. Also, there's no need to assign the value of `GETDATE()` to a variable, you can simply state it in your `SELECT`.

**Assuming** that the aliases you have used are the names of the columns in your table `[DBServer].[Database].[dbo].[LkValues]` then this should work:

```
INSERT INTO Lookups (Id, [Type],[Name],CreatedName,ChangedName,CreatedDate,ChangedDate)
SELECT newid(), 
    'Type',
    [Name], 
    'A.Miller', 
    'A.Miller',
    GETDATE(),GETDATE()
FROM [DBServer].[Database].[dbo].[LkValues]
WHERE NOT [Name][] IS NULL OR [Name] = '';
```

*Edit: My guess was correct. When inserting into a table, aliases mean nothing. It's about the **order** you provide the columns, not their names. For example:*

```
CREATE TABLE #sample (column1 int, column2 int);

INSERT INTO #sample 
--inserts into the "wrong" columns
SELECT 2 AS column2, 1 AS column1;

SELECT *
FROM #sample;

INSERT INTO #sample (column2,
                     column1)
--Inserts into the wanted columns, as they are specified
SELECT 2, 1;

INSERT INTO #sample
--Inserts into the wanted columns, as they are in the same order as the table
SELECT 3 AS Column1, 4 AS Column2;

SELECT *
FROM #sample;

DROP TABLE #sample;
```

*When using an `INSERT` statement, it is considered best practice the specify the columns being inserted into in your `INSERT` clause. This helps others debug your code, as well as yourself in the future, as well as easily eliminates error like yours.*

Comment: Yes, thanks works fine for me as well. Newer servers seems to sort out the correct field order. Thank you for the quick and correct answer.

Comment: @Florian seems your "newer" servers don't have the columns in the same order. SQL Server, regardless of version, doesn't use an alias to determine the destination column. That's true for all currently supported versions (2008 - 2017). If you're newer servers are meant to be a replication of your current server, then they are not.

Comment: again you are right. On the other newer server the field order is like in my first statement, thats why it worked there.

Comment: Another reason why it's so important to specify the destination columns in your `INSERT` statement, @Florian. If your environments have different column ordering, then you must declare them, otherwise you will get different behaviour.

Comment: An upvote for my question would be great, thank you.